# using "the"+adj without a noun

Tags: adjectives, syntactic-analysis, nominalizations

Is the following sentence good/legal/understood English?

> Meditation melts the coarse and solidifies the subtle.

If it isn't, how can this be otherwise expressed, in a neat and concise way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In most European languages, `Article + Adjective` constructions can have specific reference; the German nickname for Chancellor Konrad Adenauer, for instance, was *Der Alte*, which translated literally as 'The Old One'.

While English speakers can and do often delete nouns and pronouns, in context:

- **Q:** *Do you want the red one or the blue one?* **A:** *I'll take the red, thanks.*

generally in English, constructions like that can only have [Generic](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html) reference, not Specific:

- *My great-uncle is the fat **one** in the middle.* [Specific reference = 'the fat person']
- **My great-uncle is the fat in the middle.*  [ungrammatical with no head N to modify]
- *My great-uncle is unfortunately among the fat.* [Generic reference = 'fat people']

So, *the coarse, the subtle, the ridiculous, the sublime, the stupid, the uneducated,* all are fine, **provided** that they don't refer to individual contextually specific things or people, but rather generically, to all such things, without individuation.

What's interesting is whether they have to refer to classes of people, or of things. That's a matter of interpretation, and varies a lot with the adjective and the context.

Comment: I'd go even farther and say that "the educated" etc. is plural unless a specific noun is left out (as in your "the red"); after all, it takes a plural verb: **the educated never says "don't"* v. *the educated never say "don't"*.

Comment: The Good, The Bad, and The Ugly

Comment: ... are always with us.

Comment: Note that in Spanish the article used for these nominalized adjectives is a neuter one, which cannot be used with nouns. *The Good, the Bad, and the Ugly* is *Lo Bueno, lo Malo y lo Feo*.  If you talked about ***el* viejo**, that would be the old one (masc) or the old man, and ***la* vieja** similarly the old one (fem) or the old woman.  But the noun-adjective hybrids it becomes “the (adj) thing”, so ***lo* viejo** would be the old part, or the old bit, or oldness or some such. It doesn’t work this way in Portuguese or French, which both just use a masculine article to nominalize adjectives.

Comment: "The Good, the Bad, and the Ugly is Lo Bueno, lo Malo y lo Feo": Actually in the case of the movie, it did refer to specific persons, which makes it "El Bueno, El Malo y El Feo".
http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_--5tv0rYkQg/SMfhro0NGVI/AAAAAAAAAEQ/73s4TRRzzwg/s400/El-Bueno-El-Feo-Y-El-Malo-Divx-frontal-DVD.jpg

Comment: @JohnLawler: My family is like a pork belly sandwich- My two great-aunts are the bread, and my great-uncle is the fat in the middle. :-)

Comment: @Shivadas *Really?* I never realized the three terms in the title mapped to discrete individuals; I always thought it was a more general thing. But your poster certainly makes it clear that each word applies to a particular guy.

Comment: So if we I understand correctly, when translating from Spanish "lo"+adj, describing a general group of things, the english construction "the"+adj is acceptable. Although some were reluctant with this usage.

Answer (score 4):

That's fine, assuming by "the subtle" you mean "things which are subtle".

Compare with the phrase "from the ridiculous to the sublime".

Answer (score 3):

Yes - this is an accepted form of usage. I'm fairly certain that it is used more when speaking in sweeping generalities as in your example "the coarse" and "the subtle."

This is not really less consise than the alternative "coarse thoughts" or "subtle thoughts."

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one situation in which I am pretty sure it is valid, but I don't know what it's called.

I seem to recall from my English lessons that you can use the adjective *with a capital* to mean the group of people to which this adjective applies. A well-known example being: "The Rich and the Poor".

What you're describing could be a generalization of this construction, although I wouldn't deem it correct.