# Is 'Japanese' in 'the Japanese' (people from Japan collectively) a noun or an adjective?

Tags: parts-of-speech, demonyms, nominalizations

Oxford Dictionaries classify '**Japanese**' in '**the Japanese**,' meaning people from Japan collectively, as a noun although some people I consulted insist it is an adjective. They base it on the examples '**the French**' and '**the Dutch**.'

Who is right? Or, are they both right?

> - It took them three hours to get to the Longhua Airport, used as an air force base for **the Japanese**.
> - Apart from the American Indians, **the Japanese** make some use of lily bulbs in traditional dishes. (source: [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/Japanese))

Comment: [This thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59798/using-theadj-without-a-noun) should help clear things up.

Comment: I read it, but alas it is no help for me. It just explains how abstract adjectives could be converted to nouns by adding 'the,' but my question concerns if it's an adjective or a noun. If I knew it was an adjective, then I could tell how 'the Japanese' stands right. For now, it could be a noun, it could be an adjective.

Comment: It depends on how you interpret it.  One can argue that "the Japanese" is an elided version of "the Japanese people", using "Japanese" as an adjective, or one can argue that it's a noun, with no elision.  The "rules" of English syntax were invented *after* the language.

Comment: Both your example sentences use 'the Japanese' correctly (though I'd change 'Apart from' to 'Like'. // [This Wikipedia article](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Nominal-Adjectives.htm) addresses 'nominal adjectives'. According to this, it never stops being an adjective. But some grammarians doubtless disagree. Some might even argue with the hypernym 'substantive'. The most appropriate view would be 'What does it matter what you call it? How it's used is what matters.' which I'm fairly sure @John Lawler would give.

Comment: Thanks, both of you. What do you mean by hypernym substantive, Edwin?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: If the OED lists it as a noun explicitly ([Japanese](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/japanese)), does that not automatically mean that it is not just an adjective anymore? Regardless of the discussion among grammarians; it's currently defined as a noun and it seems to me that we need to accept those definitions as correct English. From your link, "elderly" seems unrelated to "Japanese", because ["elderly" is not defined as a noun](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/elderly) (and therefore it must invariaby be a nominal adjective).

Comment: In your examples, "Japanese" is an **adjective** in a 'fused-head' construction. "The Japanese" is then a noun phrase used generically and determined by "the", where the head and the modifier "Japanese" are 'fused' into the single word "Japanese". We understand it to mean the inhabitants of Japan.

Comment: You can view *the Japanese* as ***either*** a noun ***or*** an adjective.

Comment: @Flater. No. Dictionaries are often slow to adopt new scholarship in grammar (Does OED even use the determiner/determinative classification? AHD  and RHK Webster's don't whereas Collins does.)  Both ACGEL and CGEL class the non-articles in 'the Dutch', 'the French' etc (actual examples given) as adjectives. CGEL has << 'A rather restricted range of adjectives occur [not 'undergo conversion to nouns'] in fused-head constructions with special interpretations. >> It is taken for granted that venerable grammars like the above easily trump dictionaries (even OED) in such areas.

Comment: @Sssamy Here I'll use the [RHK Webster's](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/substantive) definition, used by some grammarians: << **substantive**:  n. 
10. a pronoun, adjective, or other word or phrase functioning as a noun. >> Flater can compare the other dictionary definitions given here and hopefully realise the inadequacy of relying on anything other than a decent grammar (and sometimes even that) for this sort of information.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment BillJ wrote:

> In your examples, "Japanese" is an **adjective** in a 'fused-head' construction. "The Japanese" is then a noun phrase used generically and determined by "the", where the head and the modifier "Japanese" are 'fused' into the single word "Japanese". We understand it to mean the inhabitants of Japan.

Other commenters have mentioned the concept of nominalized adjectives. This accounts for why people can say *“the Japanese”* to mean the Japanese people, but *“*a Japanese”* sounds funny. You see the same thing when folks refer to *“the old”* but where again *“*an old”* is ungrammatical.

The OED writes that *Japanese* as a noun is:

> Formerly as true n. with pl. in *-es*; now only as adj. used absol. and unchanged for pl.: *a Japanese, two Japanese, the Japanese*.

In the Wikipedia article on nominalized adjectives, they write:

> The most common appearance of the nominalized adjective in English is when an adjective is used to indicate a collective group. This happens in the case where a phrase such as *the poor people* becomes *the poor*. The adjective *poor* is nominalized, and the noun *people* disappears. Other adjectives commonly used in this way include *rich, wealthy, homeless, disabled, blind, deaf*, etc., as well as certain demonyms such as *English, Welsh, Irish, French, Dutch*.

See also [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/59803/2085).

Comment: The OED seems contrary to what I think (and what you said prior to the OED reference). It lists 'a Japanese' and 'two Japanese' presumably for what I would say as 'a Japanese person' or 'two Japanese people'. Am I misreading your OED quote?

Answer (score 0):

### They are nouns*

**in my layman's opinion.*

> The Japanese
>   The French
>   The Dutch

While these are all correct, the same does not apply to some other nationalities:

> The Belgian**s**
>   The South African**s**

I've looked up all five nationalities in the OED, and I noticed that for all five nationalities, **the words are also explicitly defined nouns**.

[Japanese](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/japanese), 
[French](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/french), 
[Dutch](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dutch#Dutch_Adjective_001), 
[Belgian](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/belgian), 
[South African](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/south_african)

It seems to me that "the Japanese" is a noun. It stands to reason that its usage is *based on* the original adjective.
It just **happens to be** the same as the adjective, but there is a separate definition for the noun and the adjective in the OED, thus making them separate words, grammatically speaking.

### Interesting to note

The first three examples all end in an *"s"*-like sound, which makes it hard to hear the difference between singular and plural. I have a feeling this is related, because this distinction seems to apply to **every** nationality I can think of.

> The Swede**s**
>   The Finnish
>   The Danish
>   The Russian**s**
>   The Chinese
>   The Bulgarian**s**
>   The American**s**
>   *and many, many more...*

**edit** [Here is a list of nationalities.](http://www.vocabulary.cl/Basic/Nationalities.htm)
I've browsed the majority of the list and the presence of a plural "s" (when referring to the people) seems to always correlate to whether the nationality ends in an *"s"*-like sound.

---

### There is an exception...

Thanks to GEdgar for pointing it out.

[Finnish](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/finnish) is not defined as a noun when referring to the **people** (only when referring to the language).
In this case, "the Finnish" would be a *nominal adjective* (as per Edwin Ashworth's comment), not a noun.

(Unless the absence of this defined noun is a mistake in the OED, but I can't know that based on its absence.)

1. If it is defined as a noun in the dictionary, then you should consider it a **noun**.
2. If no noun is found, but the word is defined as an adjective, then you should consider it a **nominal adjective**.
3. If it is not defined as a noun or an adjective, then it is **not correct** English (unless loan words are considered correct even if not defined? I'm not quite sure about that)

Comment: The Finnish or the Finns?  The Danish or the Danes?  The Scottish or the Scots?

Comment: @GEdgar: The existence of synonyms doesn't really change the fact that the words are all defined as nouns (in the OED). If anything, your examples are further examples of the plural "s" appearing only where there is no "s" sound already. **Note** I checked your examples, and "Finnish" is the only one that is not defined as a noun in the OED (when referring to the people. It is still defined as a noun for the language). So it would be correct to say that "the Finnish" (referring to the people) is a nominal adjective (see Edwin Ashworth's comment to the question)

Comment: People definitely say *I am a Japanese*, *I am a Chinese*, *I am an American* and *I am a Russian*. Does anybody ever say *I am a Finnish* or *I am a Danish*? I think they'd say *I am a Finn* or *I am a Dane*.

Comment: @PeterShor: "_I am a Chinese_" I have never heard this phrase. You do hear _I am Chinese_ and _I am a Chinese [noun]_. In both cases, that is the adjective. The same applies to Japanese. Russian doesn't quite seem to fit your list of examples, as it is strictly defined as [_a single Russian national_](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/Russian), "Russian" never refers to the country's citizens collectively.

Comment: You can say *the living* and *the dead*, as well. But *dead* and *living* are not nouns, they're adjectives. You'd never say *I am a dead* or *I am a living*. So why do you think *the Finnish* is not also an adjective, if you can't say *I am a Finnish*?

Comment: @PeterShor: I never said that nominal adjectives don't exist. They do. They apply in cases where **there is no defined noun** (the elderly, the living, the dead) But in the case of Japanese (and other nationalities, apparently with the exception of Finnish), there is an **established explicit definition of the word as a noun** (when referring to the country's nationals).

Comment: The OED gives as a citation under the noun Japanese: *Dialogue between a Japanese and a Formosan.* So when they say the noun "Japanese", they include the construction *I am a Japanese.* This is why they don't list *Finnish as a noun*; nobody ***ever*** says *I am a Finnish*.

Comment: @PeterShor: Fair enough, though it still seems more rare than the counterexamples I provided (yours is of course still _correct_ regardless). But that still does not invalidate my answer, as "Japanese" is still explicitly defined to refer to the collective (all of Japan's nationals) as well, regardless of any other definitions of the word.

Comment: @PeterShor: _"This is why they don't list Finnish as a noun; nobody ever says I am a Finnish."_ You are conflating the idea of a noun that refers to _a single national_ and a noun that refers to _all nationals_. These two have nothing to do with each other from a grammatical perspective as far as I'm aware, even if their spelling happens to be the same. Different definitions should apply (no one says "the Russian" for _all Russian nationals_ either). There is no automatic relationship where a singular refers to a collective, or vice versa.

Comment: A noun that refers to ***all*** nationals can also sometimes be viewed as an adjective. This is why you can say *the Finnish, the Danish, the Spanish, the French,* and *the dead* when you would say *I am a Finn, Dane, Spaniard, Frenchman*, or *dead man.* And also why the OED does not consider *Finnish* a noun. If you allow for this kind of collective meaning, nearly all adjectives would have to be considered a noun.

Comment: @PeterShor: _"A noun that refers to all nationals can also sometimes be viewed as an adjective."_ You're wrong. It's the other way around, an adjective can be used _as a noun_. This is a **nominal adjective**, which both me and Edwin Ashworth have been discussing already (**and you mentioned it too**, when you referred to "the living" and "the dead" in an earlier comment). Your statement doesn't even apply to your example of "the Finnish" **as it is not defined as a noun** (when referring to the nationals).

Comment: @PeterShor: Your last few comments do not question the validity of my answer, nor provide a meaningful correction. You've started contradicting yourself and are giving examples that don't fit your own alleged rule. I'm sorry but this is a pointless discussion.

Comment: @PeterShor You’d think someone proclaiming themselves a danish would risk being confused with a jelly doughnut — or a Kennedy. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's an adjective, since it can be modified by the adverb "partly".  Nouns can't be modified by adverbs.

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/japanese  ~ I'm sure that like many other words, Japanese may be used as either a noun or an adjective, depending on context.