# Does "few" have some concrete/historical meaning as a noun?

Tags: etymology, nouns, pronouns

"A small few" - I've heard (and read) this used. It's made me think... is the word "few" meaningful as a noun rather than a pronoun? Or rather, does it have some historical origin in something usable as a noun

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. Always, reasonable research should accompany a question on ELU.

Comment: As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Few) explains, 'The Few' became a standard expression after the famous speech by Churchill.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: That's indeed what I asked.

Comment: @user5768790: Nope, Edwin understood what I meant.

Comment: This is a twist on the ['nominalised adjective'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/404639/is-japanese-in-the-japanese-people-from-japan-collectively-a-noun-or-an-ad/427273#427273) (the poor / the sick / the well-off / the opposite / the Japanese ...) because 'few' and 'a few' aren't adjectives to start with: they're quantifiers. Though appropriate modification (the exact opposite / the very rich / the inventive Japanese ...) is usually possible with nominalised adjectives, ...

Comment: I can't see this as acceptable with 'A few [were saved]', except possibly with 'A very few [were saved].' With nominalised numerals it can be (The Famous Five / ...The Temperance Seven / The Tamworth Two ...). I'd regard these as fixed idiomatic expressions, compounds, along with 'The Few'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I would tend to agree if we were talking about "the few". But "A small few" seems to be something else.

Comment: "I can't see this [premodification] as acceptable with 'A few [were saved]' " causes you problems? And note that your title question licenses the consideration of an added definite article to 'few' in checking for nounal or noun-like behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like what the *OED* describes under adjective definition **2.b.**

Definition **2.** as a whole:

> Like the cardinal numerals, *few* may be used to form with a plural n. a virtual collective noun, preceded by *a, every,* or (rarely) *that*, but construed with plural verb.

and **2.b.** describes this use as maintaining adjectival form with ellipsis of the noun, as in "a small few."

> with ellipsis of **n.** Often followed by *of*. Also absol. **a few persons**; occasionally with an adj., as **a faithful few**, **a select few**, etc. *few*, in which it approaches the nature of a n. *†a fewer*: a smaller number of.

So note that, as you do in your question, the *OED* observes that it ***approaches the nature of a n[oun]***.  But for its part, the *OED* still explains this through the context of an adjective with a dropped noun, not by defining "few" as a noun itself.

It compares this with use of numerals, so just like you might say

> The fantastic **four people**.

or

> The fantastic **four**.

... these uses of **few** follow a similar pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The nominal use of *few* [dates back to ca. 1300](https://www.etymonline.com/word/few), often in contrast to *the many*, though the word itself (OE *feawe*) descends from a Germanic root now extant only in English *few* and Scandinavian *få* ("few"), but no longer in German or Dutch.

In traditional grammar,  *[few](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/few?s=t)* can be an adjective/determiner, a substantivized adjective, a noun, and a pronoun. Beyond the adjectival use, how one assigns these parts of speech has more to do with modifiers than any function within a sentence.

I invited the whole group to the party,

- but only a few people showed up. *Adjective, modifying people.*
- but [pitifully few](http://nyanglish.com/pitifully-few) showed up. *Substantivized adjective. Nouns or pronouns cannot be modified by an adverb.*
- but few showed up.  *Pronoun.*
- but a (faithful, grateful; tiny, small) few showed up. *Noun. An indefinite article can't modify a pronoun or adjective. Pronouns can't be modified by adjectives.*
- but the (faithful, precious) few who did had a great time. *Noun, as a class, though obviously only a small number.*

.

Comment: Pretty sure that you can always use a quantifier like this in ellipsis as though it were a substantive itself. But it's still the thing it used to be: "Very few would disagree" has *very* modifying it, which you can't do if it's truly a noun or pronoun. All the other quantifiers I can think of can be used as substantives themselves the way *few* can there: *many, most, some, all, any, each, none, either, neither, both,* and so on. (Although not all allow for modification by *very*.)

Comment: Substantivized adj.: One can say both _the ostentatious rich_ and the _ostentatiously rich_, but only _the completely innocent_. Participles like _the recently deceased_ are uncontroversial. I wouldn't consider _very_ merely to be incidental. _Everyone/body, no one/nobody_ can be modified by adverbs (scarcely, almost, practically, etc.) but only by splitting the compound. "Zero head" or "fused head" might solve the problem for some.