# Can adjectives alone be nouns? Is 'Like other French who lived through the war ...' acceptable?

Tags: word-usage

*The Pope then asked: 'Are there **any English** here?'*

*Like **other French** who lived through the war, he’s trying to pass on to younger generations the gratitude he feels.*

These are taken respectively from a book titled "A Traveller in Rome" (by H. V. Morton) and a news article titled "Normandy tries to keep alive ‘infinite gratitude’ for D-Day" (published by MilitaryTime.com https://www.militarytimes.com/military-honor/salute-veterans/2019/05/29/normandy-tries-to-keep-alive-infinite-gratitude-for-d-day/)

The word "English" is an adjective and that's why you call someone from England an Englishman or Englishwoman, not **an English**. The same goes for French and you call someone from France a Frenchman or Frenchwoman, not **a French**.

Why is it "Are there **any English** here?", not "Are there **any English people** here? Also, why is it "Like **other French** who lived through the war", not "Like **other French people** who lived through the war"?

Comment: For place names, the adjective form is commonly used as a noun - e.g. Australian, American, Athenian, etc. For other adjectives, that's not so common - e.g. fat, skinny, etc.

Comment: That certainly does sound odd.

Comment: @tchrist What sounds odd?

Comment: @Lawrence Both his examples in bold sound wrong to me. It's common enough to nominalize adjectives when these refer to people (*the rich and the poor*; *the good, the bad, and the ugly*), but attempting to appropriate adjectives for use as demonyms / gentilics when we already have existing terms suggests a poor grasp of English. You wouldn't say *Other Spanish who lived through the war* because we have a specific noun that means Spanish people: *Spaniards*. If you don't want to use it, then you need to say what noun you want *Spanish* to modify.

Comment: @tchrist Good point, though I don't know very many places that have their own specialist demonym.

Comment: Closely related:  [Is 'Japanese' in 'the Japanese' (people from Japan collectively) a noun or an adjective?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/404639/is-japanese-in-the-japanese-people-from-japan-collectively-a-noun-or-an-ad)  (see tchrist's article, where he quotes that 'two Japaneses' was once acceptable but now isn't, and mentions the 'fused head' analysis).

Comment: I'll say that to my ears, (?)"Are there any English/French here?" sounds better than ?/*'Like other English/French who lived through the war' and much better than *'4 English/French raced along the street'.

Comment: I've checked on [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=other+French+who%2Cother+English+who&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cother%20French%20who%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cother%20English%20who%3B%2Cc0); there are _some_ relevant recent examples  (in histories) (not really a surprise) for 'other French who' and 'other English who', but I'd say the usage is rarefied.

Comment: We're not just talking about the English and the French. I wonder if it sounds natural to say "Are there any American/German/Italian here?", not "Are there any Americans/Germans/Italians here?".

Comment: I'd like to know if native English speakers would consider such usage standard English.

Comment: According to Dr. Lawler, the "Article + Adjective" constructions are fine only when they don't refer to individual, specific things or people, not to mention the use of "the Article". I suspect "Any" and "Other" are not relevant.

Comment: It is totally unnatural to say *Are there any American/German/Polish/Swedish here*?

Comment: @PeterShor Danishes would be ok, though. :)

Comment: @Peter Shor Thank you. But American/German/Italian/Polish/Swedish etc. are adjectives just as English/French/Spanish etc. are, aren't they?

Comment: 'According to Dr. Lawler, the "Article + Adjective" constructions are fine only when ...' Can you link to this, please, Choe? It sounds like a duplicate (if it's on ELU), and at least is an answer to your question.

Comment: @tchrist But _Berliners_ and _Hamburgers_ are made to a German recipe.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59798/using-theadj-without-a-noun/59803#59803 This is the link, which I happened to come across thanks to Mr. Ashworth's comment up there.

Answer (score 2):

There are many nationalities for which the adjective and noun are the same: *Indian, German, Russian, Mexican, Yemeni*.

For France and England, the standard nouns are *Frenchmen* and *Englishmen*. These really are not consistent with gender-neutral language; I suspect the author replaced them with *French* and *English* in the interest of gender neutrality.

Is this a good idea? It's probably better than *Engliards*,  *Engles* and *Englanders* (modeled after *Spanish/Spaniard*, *Swedish/Swede*, and *Iceland/Icelander*). And if people keep on doing this, it will stop sounding funny.

Comment: I was wondering if it's possible to nominalize them that way at all, I mean, if they're valid.

Comment: There are currently no non-weird-sounding gender-neutral nouns for these. I suspect that 50 years from now, there will be (of course, they still sound weird to us now).

Comment: The second one, the article, is written by a professional journalist from Associated Press, which is the reason I am puzzled.

Comment: 'Brit' is an unmarked (other than for informality) term that's very convenient and widely used. I don't think that  'Frenchie' is similarly unmarked.

Comment: @ChoeGuevara it’s always worth remembering that style guides also sometimes have specific wording to use, and AP style is distinct in many instances.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, adjectives can substitute for nouns **in the plural**, as both your examples are. We traditionally speak of *the wounded, the poor* etc. However, it's nowadays considered less impersonal to say, for example *disabled people* rather than *the disabled.*

Comment: All adjectives? And note that OP gives specific usages; nominal forms such as 'the poor', 'the English', with the definite article, have been [covered before](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59798/using-theadj-without-a-noun).

Comment: They can also be used in the singular. I frequently hear tennis broadcasters refer to the Swiss tennis player Roger Federer (the person) as ***the Swiss***. (For example: *The Swiss **is** giving a master class.*)